# Is there a way in Swift 2.0 to start a tuple-for-loop from a certain index of an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, tuples

I want to start a for in loop (using a tuple) with the value of the index in 2nd position.

```
myArray = [9,1,8,2,7,3,7,94,5]


for (index, element) in myArray.enumerate(){

}
```

How can I do to start it in the 2nd position of the array? (with index 1 and element 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `dropFirst` or `dropLast` on an enumeration:

```
let myArray = [9,1,8,2,7,3,7,94,5]

for (index, element) in myArray.enumerate().dropFirst() {
  print(index, " - ", element)
}

for (index, element) in (myArray.enumerate().dropFirst(3)) {
  print(index, " - ", element)
}
```

Comment: Note that none of the dropFirst solutions will maintain the original indexing.  The first index received will be 0, not 1.

Comment: If you drop after you enumerate then the tuples will have the original index of the value.

Comment: Good point.  Make that "none of the other dropFirst solutions" :)

Comment: Great! `enumerate()` has been renamed to `enumerated()` (I think in Swift 3).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe ?

```
myArray = [9,1,8,2,7,3,7,94,5]

for (index, element) in myArray.enumerate() where index > 0 {

}
```

Comment: Yes outside of the loop

Answer (score 2):

```
for (index, element) in myArray[1..<myArray.count].enumerate() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The is the simplest way I can think of.

```
for (index, element) in myArray.enumerate().dropFirst() {

}
```

or if you want to customize the start index

```
let startIndex = 1
for (index, element) in myArray.enumerate().dropFirst(startIndex) {

}
```